# Intellij Idea does not pick up my changes unless I build my module

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My team's integration test code is written in Java. Gradle is our build tool. We are using testng as the test framework tool. I am using Intellij Idea IDE.

Each time I make any change in my code (even printing messages) while writing my tests, Intellij Idea does not pick up my latest changes unless and build my module.

Is this the expected behaviour? Is there setting that I need to toggle in order to make Intellij to use my latest code without having to build it each time for minor changes ?

Comment: Please check that your Run configuration Before Launch steps includes compilation/build. For faster builds you can use IntelliJ IDEA compiler instead of Gradle: https://i.imgur.com/HpeUaUE.png. If the issue persists, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could you please add more information about the version of IntelliJ you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Probably your IntelliJ is not configured for auto-build (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-applications.html#auto-build), try this:

- Press Ctrl+Alt+S to open the IDE settings and select Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler.
- On the Compiler page, select Build project automatically.
- Now when you make changes in the class files, IntelliJ IDEA automatically performs the incremental build of the project.
- The automatic build also gets triggered when you save the file (Ctrl+S) or when you have the Save files automatically if application is idle for N sec. option selected in the System settings dialog.

Check also the section "Compile before running" : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-applications.html#compile_before_run